# Sort an array of strings in C#

Tags: c#, sorting

How can I sort an array of strings using the `OrderBy` function? I saw I need to implement some interfaces...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sort the array by using.

```
var sortedstrings = myStringArray.OrderBy( s => s );
```

This will return an instance of `Ienumerable`. If you need to retain it as a array, use this code instead.

```
myStringArray = myStringArray.OrderBy( s => s ).ToArray();
```

I'm not sure what you are referring to when you said that you have to implement some interfaces, but you do not have to do this when using the `IEnumerable.OrderBy`. Simply pass a `Func<TSource, TKey>` in the form of a lambda-expression.

Comment: @aharon: It's the lambda expression's parameter. If you're going to learn LINQ, you'll need to learn about various features from C# 3.

Comment: Nit: you don't pass a `Predicate<T>` into OrderBy - you pass a `Func<TSource, TKey>`.

Comment: Whoops. A type there. Fixed it now. A predicate would obviously not help in orderby. Thanks Jon and Mark.

Answer (score 3):

`OrderBy` won't sort the existing array in place. If you need to do that, use [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx).

`OrderBy` always returns a *new* sequence - which of course you can convert to an array and store a reference to in the original variable, as per Øyvind's answer.

Answer (score 2):

To sort *inside* an existing array, call `Array.Sort(theArray)`.

Re your comment on interfaces: you don't need to add any interfaces here, since `string` is well supported; but for *custom* types (of your own) you can implement `IComparable` / `IComparable<T>` to enable sorting. You can *also* do the same passing in an `IComparer` / `IComparer<T>`, if you want (or need) the code that provides the ordering to be separate to the type itself.

Answer (score 0):

Linq has two (syntax) ways to sort an array of strings.

1:

```
string[] sortedStrings = unsortedStrings.OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();
```

This syntax is using a [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) if you don't know what `s => s` means.

2:

```
sortedStrings = (from strings in unsortedStrings  
                 orderby strings  
                 select strings).ToArray();
```

This example looks a bit like a SQL statement and is probably easier to read if you are new with Linq.

`ToArray()` converts the `IOrderedEnumerable<string>` to as `string[]` in this case.

Comment: what type is the unsorted? I tried with string[], not working... ?

Comment: string[] test = new[] { "3", "1", "c"}; should work without problems.  You need to include namespace System.Linq